# Mysql Adjancency: get all parents of the leaf

Tags: mysql, adjacency-list

I have a table in the category where I use this data structure model. Also use another table that shows me the path of the branch of a category:

```
**t_category**
id | name | parent
------------------
1   mascot   null
2   cat      1
3   dog      1
4   doberman 3

**t_category_path**
id | path
------------------
1   /1/
2   /1/2/
3   /1/3/
4   /1/3/4/
```

What I want is to get the list of parents of any item. For example if I search "dog" get "dog, mascot" and if I search "doberman" should get "doberman, dog, mascot"

I tried this ... but it is the reverse, I mean looking for the parents get the leaves:

```
SELECT
    c2.id,
    c2.name,
    p.path
FROM t_category c, t_category c2, t_category_path p, t_category_path p2
WHERE c.id = 1
AND p2.id = c.id
AND p.path LIKE(CONCAT(p2.path,'%'))
AND c2.id = p.id
ORDER BY p.path ASC;
```

and obviously get:

```
id | name | path
------------------
1   mascot   /1/
2   cat      /1/2/
3   dog      /1/3/
4   doberman /1/3/4/
```

but I want from "doberman" obtained:

```
id | name | path
------------------
1   mascot   /1/
3   dog      /1/3/
4   doberman /1/3/4/
```

Is possible to consult from a leaf?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably break out the delineated data in the path field. Use something like this:

```
id | depth | parent
4    2       3
4    1       1
3    1       1
3    2       3
```

ect...

Then you could do:

> SELECT * FROM t_category_path WHERE id = 4